# referencing an array that's stored in a cell within a formula

Tags: excel-formula

`=INDEX($AT$1:$AY$66,MATCH("REGULAR PAY *",$AT$1:$AT$66,0),3)`

Because I use this same array value (`$AT$1:$AY$66`) in multiple formulas across the sheet (and it could change at some point) it would be nice if I could put `$AT$1:$AY$66` into a cell and reference it within this formula. So far I haven't had any luck being able to do that.

Comment: Will the columns change or just the number of rows?

Comment: Why can't you use a named range?

Comment: Peter K - I didn't know about the named range thing, looks pretty cool!

Comment: Scott, just rows probably.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get past this now by using INDIRECT(BF7) in place of my AT1:AY66 where BF7 is where I have AT1:AY66. Now if it happens that I need to change that array to AT1:AY70 for example I can just change it in BF7 and it will alter all my formulas accordingly.